# How to host .php files on apache2 - ubuntu?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04

I am hosting my web application for my maturita exam on google cloud. So I created VM (running on ubuntu) and installed apache2 on it. Then I installed PHP successfully. The problem is, it is hosting only .html files even though I installed PHP properly. When i try to host .php file an HTTP ERROR 500 will ocur.
The phpinfo.php is the only file thats working.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

My question is. How do I change configuration of apache on Google clouds ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is the component of your setup that will process code to display dynamic content. It can run scripts, connect to your MySQL databases to get information, and hand the processed content over to your web server to display.

Once again, leverage the apt system to install PHP. In addition, include some helper packages this time so that PHP code can run under the Apache server and talk to your MySQL database:

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
```

This should install PHP without any problems. We’ll test this in a moment.

In most cases, you will want to modify the way that Apache serves files when a directory is requested. Currently, if a user requests a directory from the server, Apache will first look for a file called index.html. We want to tell the web server to prefer PHP files over others, so make Apache look for an index.php file first.

To do this, type this command to open the dir.conf file in a text editor with root privileges:

sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
It will look like this:

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Move the PHP index file (highlighted above) to the first position after the DirectoryIndex specification, like this:

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

When you are finished, save and close the file by pressing CTRL+X. Confirm the save by typing Y and then hit ENTER to verify the file save location.

After this, restart the Apache webserver in order for your changes to be recognized. Do this by typing this:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

You can also check on the status of the apache2 service using systemctl:

```
sudo systemctl status apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 500 error can be caused by a problem with your Apache configurations. If your code generate a 500 error, check to make sure they have permission to run in the directory where they are located. Apache will not allow programs to execute by default. So try to give permission to your virtual host directory with CHMOD.

And also for more details about the error you should check Apache error log like:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```